# How to t-test by group in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I have quite a huge pandas dataframe with many columns. The dataframe contains two groups. It is basically setup as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = [{"air" : 0.47,"co2" : 0.43 , "Group" : 1}, {"air" : 0.77,"co2" : 0.13 , "Group" : 1}, {"air" : 0.17,"co2" : 0.93 , "Group" : 2} ]
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
```

I want to perform a t-test paired t-test on `air` and `co2` thereby compare the two groups `Group = 1` and `Group = 2`.

I have many many more columns than just `air` `co2`- hence, I would like to find a procedure that works for all columns int the dataframe. I believe, I could use `scipy.stats.ttest_rel` together with `pd.groupby` oder `apply`. How would that work? Thanks in advance /R

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use pandas dataframe.where method.

```
group1_air = df.where(df.Group== 1).dropna()['air']
group2_air = df.where(df.Group== 2).dropna()['air']
```

This bit of code returns into group1_air all the values of the air column where the group column is 1 and all the values of air where group is 2 in group2_air.
The `drop.na()` is required because the `.where` method will return NAN for every row in which the specified conditions is not met. So all rows where group is 2 will return with NAN values when you use `df.where(df.Group== 1)`.

Whether you need to use `scipy.stats.ttest_rel` or `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` depends on your groups. If you samples are from independent groups you should use `ttest_ind` if your samples are from related groups you should use `ttest_rel`.

So if your samples are independent from oneanother your final piece of required code is.

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(group1_air,group2_air)
```

else you need to use

```
scipy.stats.ttest_rel(group1_air,group2_air)
```

When you want to also test co2 you simply need to change air for co2 in the given example.

Edit:

This is a rough sketch of the code you should run to execute ttests over every column in your dataframe except for the group column. You may need to tamper a bit with the `column_list` to get it completely compliant with your needs (you may not want to loop over every column for example).

```
# get a list of all columns in the dataframe without the Group column
column_list = [x for x in df.columns if x != 'Group']
# create an empty dictionary
t_test_results = {}
# loop over column_list and execute code explained above
for column in column_list:
    group1 = df.where(df.Group== 1).dropna()[column]
    group2 = df.where(df.Group== 2).dropna()[column]
    # add the output to the dictionary 
    t_test_results[column] = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(group1,group2)
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(t_test_results,orient='Index')
results_df.columns = ['statistic','pvalue']
```

At the end of this code you have a dataframe with the output of the ttest over every column you will have looped over.

Comment: This is a very nice answer for a one-by-one case. However, I am trying to ttest for `air` and `co2` and many many more in go. Any idea how to make that happen?